# xrandr problem and change rotate

Tags: 17.10

After install Ubuntu, my screen has rotate to right.

I am using this commands:

```
xrandr -o normal
xrandr -o right
xrandr -o left
xrandr -o invented
```

I have receive this error:

```
Failed to change the screen configuration.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you are using ?

Comment: @Rooney please see tags :)